# differentiate duplicate values in a column based on another

Tags: pandas

I have the following df:

```
       key   name        
0       1      'AA'
1       1      'AA'
2       3      'BB'
3       3      'BB'
4       4      'CC'
5       4      'CC'
6       2      'AA'
7       2      'AA'
```

How could I differentiate repeated name by adding a space at the end of the name for those names that are the same but have different key?

```
       key   name        
0       1      'AA'
1       1      'AA'
2       3      'BB'
3       3      'BB'
4       4      'CC'
5       4      'CC'
6       2      'AA ' # we add the space because it has the same name and different key
7       2      'AA ' # we add the space because it has the same name and different key
```

**Edit:**

As @ALollz pointed out , if there where 3 repeated values in column names then there will be 2 spaces after the second ocurrence:

```
'AA  '
```

Comment: And what if 'AA' appears in three keys, do you want to get the values 'AA', 'AA ' and 'AA  '? (0, 1, 2 spaces)

Comment: @ALollz correct, sorry for not specifiying it

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really care about which one gets the additional spaces, you could `rank` each key using `dense` to determine how many spaces to add. If your DataFrame is sorted such that lower keys of the same name appear first, this will add the additional spaces to later rows, like in your example.

```
s = (df.groupby('name').key.rank('dense')-1).astype(int)

df['name'] = df.name + pd.Series(' ', index=s.index).str.repeat(repeats=s)
   key name
0    1   AA
1    1   AA
2    3   BB
3    3   BB
4    4   CC
5    4   CC
6    2  AA 
7    2  AA
```

Comment: @ge00rge what does?

Comment: sorry, the first line s = (df.groupby('name').key.rank('dense')-1).astype(int) returns  'NoneType' object is not callable